# Using googlescript deleteRow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying use google script delete Row 1500 until last row

```
    function DeleteR() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sn = ss.getSheetByName("xxx");
  if( sn.getLastRow() > 1500 ) {
    sn.deleteRows(1500,sn.getLastRow()-1500+1);
  }
  var sn2 = ss.getSheetByName("xxx2");
  if( sn2.getLastRow() > 1500 ) {
    sn2.deleteRows(1500,sn2.getLastRow()-1500+1);
  }
  var sn3 = ss.getSheetByName("xxx3");
  if( sn3.getLastRow() > 1500 ) {
    sn3.deleteRows(1500,sn3.getLastRow()-1500+1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Description**

Use Sheet.deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany)

**Script**

```
function DeleteR() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sn = ss.getSheetByName("xxx");
  if( sn.getLastRow() > 1500 ) {
    sn.deleteRows(1500,sn.getLastRow()-1500+1);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Sheet.deleteRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteRows(Integer,Integer))

Comment: Hi TheWizEd thx your answer,this is my new script but still wont work you know what's wrong

Comment: Pho, don't post it as an answer.  Edit your original post.  And all I can say is are you sure there are more than 1500 rows?  And does the execution log show any errors?

Comment: Yes i am sure more than 1500 rows,notice is showing Execution completed but i check back 3 sheet nothing has changed

Comment: Sorry maybe it should be `if( sn.getLastRow() >= 1500 ) {`? How many rows are there?

Comment: I have found the problem because I have a lot of empty rows in my data

Comment: Script only delete rows with values